# Spring Security oAuth2 getting unauthorized error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am following this tutorial [spring-oauth2-role-based-authorization](https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-oauth2-role-based-authorization) .
The code base is exactly the same described in the blog.

I am doing exactly what is being said. But still I am getting unauthorized error.
[postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur0Qb.png)

[postman request 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzbJA.png)

[postman error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvNEA.png)

```
{
"timestamp": "2019-08-14T05:12:48.966+0000",
"status": 401,
"error": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Unauthorized",
"path": "/oauth/token"
```

}

I tried many advice from other blog posts or previous answer but nothing is working.

I definitely need some help. I would be thankful for your time.

```
2019-08-14 13:54:55 INFO o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] 2019-08-14 13:54:55 INFO o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '' 2019-08-14 13:54:55 INFO c.d.r.RoleBasedOauth2Application - Started RoleBasedOauth2Application in 51.897 seconds (JVM running for 54.954) 2019-08-14 13:54:55 DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'local.server.port' in PropertySource 'server.ports' with value of type Integer 2019-08-14 13:55:26 INFO o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet' 2019-08-14 13:55:26 INFO o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet' 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data 2019-08-14 13:55:26 INFO o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 19 ms 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token'] 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token' 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - matched 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter' 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter' 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter' 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter' 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET] 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'GET /logout' 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST] 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/logout' 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT] 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'PUT /logout' 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE] 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout' 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - No matches found 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /oauth/token at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter' 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.w.BasicAuthenticationFilter - Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'client' 2019-08-14 13:55:26 DEBUG o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider 2019-08-14 13:55:27 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'scopedTarget.clientDetailsService' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.a.d.DaoAuthenticationProvider - Authentication failed: password does not match stored value 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.w.BasicAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request for failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint - Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest] 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint - No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@60d2d741 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@60d2bd6f 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token'] 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/oauth/token' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key'] 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/oauth/token_key' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token'] 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/oauth/check_token' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - No matches found 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET] 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'POST /error' doesn't match 'GET /logout' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST] 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/logout' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT] 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'POST /error' doesn't match 'PUT /logout' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE] 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'POST /error' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - No matches found 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor - Token not found in headers. Trying request parameters. 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor - Token not found in request parameters. Not an OAuth2 request. 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter - No token in request, will continue chain. 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@a5ffb05: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/oauth/token' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/oauth/authorize**' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/publica' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/admin/**' 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Public object - authentication not attempted 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={masked} 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Using 'application/json', given [/] and supported [application/json, application/+json, application/json, application/+json] 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Writing [{timestamp=Wed Aug 14 13:55:30 IST 2019, status=401, error=Unauthorized, message=Unauthorized, path= (truncated)...] 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 401 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally 2019-08-14 13:55:30 DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

I did some further debugging its failing because encoded password does not match. But its same in the debugger console. (see below picture)
[PasswordEncoderFailed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy742.png)

Comment: pasting logs from console would help, may be set level to debug and post here

Comment: that could be helpful. let me check . Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. OMG hell lot of debugging.

The encoded password is provided as string that was creating the issue.
When I changed it into

```
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

passwordEncoder.encode("changeit")
```

It worked. Thanks Waqas for guiding me to debug it inside framework.